# How to make cypress different test depending on if there are rows

Tags: vuejs2, cypress

In @vue/cli 4.0.5 app making cypress for a bloc like

```
<fieldset class="blocks m-1 p-1">
  <legend class="blocks block-wrapper-for-data-listing">Events&nbsp;</legend>
  <div class="table-responsive table-wrapper-for-data-listing" v-if="taskRow.events.length">
    <table class="table table-striped table-data-listing">
      ...
      <!--- DATA TABLE -->
    </table>
  </div>
  <p class="alert alert-info m-1 p-1 wrapper-for-no-rows-data-listing" role="alert" v-if="!taskRow.events.length">
    This task has no events yet!
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

I want to make different conditions depending on if there are taskRow.events rows.
I made rules when there are taskRow.eventsL :

```
var view_event_details_found = false;
cy.get(".block-wrapper-for-data-listing")
  .get(".table-wrapper-for-data-listing")
  .then(listing => {
    alert("::-1");
    cy.get(".tr_view_event_details")
      .find(".view_event_details")
      .first()
      .click();
    cy.contains(".modal-title", "Event Details");
    view_event_details_found = true;
  });

alert("view_event_details_found::" + view_event_details_found);
if (!view_event_details_found) {
}
```

I tried when view_event_details_found = false to make other test on 
search “This task has no events yet!” text.

But I got error :

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: '.table-wrapper-for-data-listing', but never found it.
```

as without div with “.table-wrapper-for-data-listing” defined.
Which is valid way to make this test ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading this https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#The-DOM-is-unstable 
docs  I made tests :

```
cy.get('.block-wrapper-for-data-listing').then(($legend) => {
    let $nxtElement = $legend.next()
    if ($nxtElement.hasClass('table-wrapper-for-data-listing')  ) {
        cy.get('.tr_view_event_details').find('.view_event_details').first().click()
        cy.contains('.modal-title', 'Event Details')
    } else {
        cy.get('p.wrapper-for-no-rows-data-listing').contains('This task has no events yet!')
    }
})
```

and that works for me in both cases whe taskRow.events.length == 0 and  taskRow.events.length> 0 !